# call nodeJS while request arrive

Tags: node.js

Hello I am new in nodeJS, I am trying to broadcast message when any new request arrive.

I am trying ajax calling and send **ttype** variable and broadcast to all browsers but My problem is when I request arrive

```
 socket.emit('date', {'date': ttype});
```

not working. but when I checked it on my nodeJs console it's show tyype and it's value. here is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var server;


var ttype = "";

    server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        // your normal server code
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        ttype = queryObject.type;

        switch (path){
            case '/':


                fs.readFile(__dirname + path + "test.html", function(err, data){
                    if (err){
                         console.log('error');
                        //return send404(res);
                    }

                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': path == 'json.js' ? 'text/javascript' : 'text/html'});
                    res.write(data, 'utf8');
                    res.end();
                    sendMessage(ttype);

                });
                break;
            case '/test.html':
                fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
                    if (err){ 
                        return send404(res);
                    }
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': path == 'json.js' ? 'text/javascript' : 'text/html'});
                    res.write(data, 'utf8');
                    res.end();
                });
            break;
            default: send404(res);
        }
    }),

    send404 = function(res){
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('404');
        res.end();
    };

    server.listen(8076);
    sendMessage = function(ttype){

         var iio = require('socket.io').listen(server);
         iio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            socket.emit('date', {'date': ttype});
            console.log('in side connection');
         });
   }

    // use socket.io
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    // define interactions with client
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket,data){

        socket.emit('date', {'date': ttype});

        setInterval(function(){
                //socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
         }, 5000);
        //recieve client data
        socket.on('client_data', function(data){
            process.stdout.write(data.letter);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why are you starting two separate socket.io servers on the same port?  That's not going to work.

Comment: @jfriend00 here is socket.io code in my view <script type="text/javascript">    
      var socket = io.connect('http://172.16.7.37:8076');
      
      socket.on('date', function(date){
        //angular.element(document.getElementById('MyControllerId')).scope().get_all_rooms();
        console.log('I am client calling.....');
      });

Comment: When I un comment line //socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()}); my view shows "i am client calling...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you'd like to let all browsers know that there is a new request by sending them ttype. All you would have to do is change your sendMessage function to:

sendMessage = function(ttype){

```
        io.emit('date', {'date': ttype});
        console.log('in side connection');
```

}

Comment: Thankyou!! but I change in view section >> socket.emit('message', 'Message to all units. I repeat, message to all units.') when request is require and this line send message to server.js which response. like >>     socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('Data received from client : '+data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('date', {'date': data});
    });